# Where should I use database and where do i use tables in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I Just learnig the PHP scipt and Mysql. My question is a simple one , where should i use tables and database.

Im Trying to create small website which can be used to create account, So when users hits sign up. should I need to create database on his name or should i need to create table?

I was thinking to create database on his name and tables on his details like tables names as profile info , gender , date of birth and email

Is that way to do? because I just started it I really need to know it. Please help me. How do I save images and videos in My database MYsql ? I installed apache last night.

Can we create infinite databases and table or does it have any limit? I said infinite because I thought to create database on user name and set tables  as profile info, recent logins and recent blogs etc. So how do i allocate them in MY sql

I thought to create database on his name and create tables based on his info. its easy to select him using mysql_select_db("passig his name").So where do I save his info?  If i need to save his blogs where do I save them ?  and when we go for tables? I thought to use tables for them.

So what would You suggest.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How to use databases is covered in most basic PHP and mySQL/sqli/PDO tutorials. See e.g. [What is a good online tutorial for PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/772349)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual approach is to create a database on a per-application basis.
Let's say your Database was named MyHomepage; in this database you have the following Tables:
tbl_users, tbl_blogs, tbl_entries

tbl_users would, as the name implies, hold user data. It has a number of fields, for instance a User ID (Unique, Auto increment), a Username, a MD5 oder SHA encrypted password, and other information like gender and so on.

tbl_blogs, holds information about the blog-instances a specific user could have: BlogID, UserID (the id of the user the blog belongs to), BlogName and so on, maybe even which software needs to be installed for this blog.

tbl_entries would hold any entry made on any blog. An Entry would have an ID, BlogID, Title, Text.

A Database an a per-User basis is usually not needed, neither is a table on a per-User or per-Blog basis needed. However - you could do that if your provider allowed you to create unlimited databases, which is usually not the case. The number of databases, as far as I know, is only limited by the amount of free space on your harddrives.

Comment: As for videos and images - I am not quite sure but it can be done. However, I'd usually use an upload-script and save the file data and the user it belongs to in a database record.

Comment: nice explaination this is what i want i need some guidance thanks and could you elabrote your comment about uploading images?

Comment: You mentioned neither table on a per user what do you mean Can you give me some more explaination please!

Comment: Imagine this scenario: 

One of your users has logged in and chose to upload a file. He would use an upload script you wrote and save the file to your web-server into a directory of your choosing. 

(For more explanation on how uploads work see here: http://de.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php )

Your script will then connect to the database and write into the userfiles table the filename and the ID of the user who uploaded it. The user will be able to select his uploaded file anytime, because the database has that specific users id.

Comment: As for "neither is a table on a per-User or per-Blog basis needed" - this is only partly true: It depends on how big your website will turn out, but you said that it's supposed to be a small website. 

What I meant is that you do not need a new table for each blog or user you create: You simply add new entries to your tables already in existence.

Answer (score 3):

You should not create neither a database, nor a table. You should create a new record in the specified table in the application's database. So your web site has 1 database. This database has a table for user profiles. Each user have a record in that table.

Comment: can we create infinite databases?

Comment: If you are worried about the number of databases (or tables) you can create, then you are using them wrong. Follow the advice in this answer and don't worry about the number of databases you can have — you only need one (per application).

Comment: @niko you can, as long as your filesystem allows it, but why would you do this?